# How to generate sha 256 hash using https url

Tags: hash, rsa, openssl

I want to generate sha256 hash of https url.

ex: url "https://www.google.com/" I want sha hash of this url.
I have tried extracting public key from ssl certificate and used following command.

```
 openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 -showcerts </dev/null 2>/dev/null | sed -n -e '/BEGIN\ CERTIFICATE/,/END\ CERTIFICATE/{/BEGIN\ /!H;/BEGIN\ /h;};$x;$p' | openssl x509 -pubkey -noout | openssl enc -base64 -d | openssl sha -sha256
```

It gives following output

"87af34d66fb3f2fd36e09111e9aba2f6f44b207f3863f3d0b54b25023909aa5"

But when I try using online tool http://passwordsgenerator.net/sha256-hash-generator/

It gives following output

"9C8908ECE489E221545E2C42A5EC0428A02A85EFB4F3A2C1E2F7DE1AE23B0332"

Can anyone tell why this giving two different output?

Comment: FYI: that `sed` cleverness is completely unnecessary because `openssl x509` already ignores any 'comments' before the first PEM CERTIFICATE block; 
`-showcerts` is also useless here because `openssl x509` processes exactly one cert never more.

Answer (score 0):

you're doing two completely different things.

the website you linked computes the hash image (SHA256) of a given string, in your case a weburl ("https://www.google.com/") and I get "D0E196A0C25D35DD0A84593CBAE0F38333AA58529936444EA26453EAB28DFC86" as output.
The same you get via the following command:

> echo -n "https://www.google.com/"

The other commandline you're using do the following:

> openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 -showcerts /dev/null

connect to the website and show its tls certificate

> sed -n -e '/BEGIN\ CERTIFICATE/,/END\ CERTIFICATE/{/BEGIN\ /!H;/BEGIN\ /h;};$x;$p'

show the base64 certificate

> openssl x509 -pubkey -noout

show the public key

> openssl enc -base64 -d

decodes it from base64

> openssl sha -sha256

computes its sha256

So as you can see, it's normal that you get two different outputs.

If ever you find a website where the two outputs are the same, please tell me. WE'LL GET A SHA256 COLLISION!!

Comment: "The same you get [from] echo -n" on SOME systems or shells; it's not universal and not even POSIX.